# which event does vtiger popup trigger when its closed?

Tags: events, triggers, vtiger

Hi I need to capture the event that triggers a popup when it is closed, for example in tickets i need to get the account that the user has selected after the popup closes, sorry about my english, it's not my mothertongue language, thanks to everyone

Comment: Could you please share the solution of it?

Answer (score 0):

In vTiger, every action passes through index.php which vtiger treats as a front controller OR you can find the repective JS file inside repective module folder inside web folder.